# It is possible in Spring to have a catch-all exception handler and annotate some exception with a specific http status?

Tags: java, spring, exception

In my Spring application, I have a catch-all exception handler in my rest controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String otherExceptions(Exception e) {
    return "Internal Server Error";
}
```

However, some exceptions are annotated with a specific http status code:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UserNotAuthenticatedException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Unfortunately, the annotated exceptions are also handled by the exception handler in the controller. Is it possible to somehow tell Spring to handle them by returning the status code they are annotated with?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two ways to handle an exception, but there's a work around for this.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String otherExceptions(Exception e) throws Exception {
    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
      throw e;

    return "Internal Server Error";
}
```

In this case, if an exception is annotated with `ResponseStatus` you rethrow the exception and let the framework handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotAuthenticatedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public String otherExceptions(Exception e) {
    return "Internal Server Error";
}
```

Create @ExceptionHandler for each separate exception class you need.

Comment: As I have multiple controllers, I do not want to have the exact same exception handler in every controller. That's why I want to use the annotation for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ControllerAdvice to handle custom exceptions for example for the exception `UserNotAuthenticatedException`  :

1) Create a generic exception

```
 public abstract class GenericException extends RuntimeException {

    public GenericException (String messageKey) {
        super(messageKey);
    }

    public GenericException (String messageKey, Throwable cause) {
        super(messageKey, cause);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract HttpStatus getHttpStatus();
}
```

2) Create a specific exception with your annotation :

```
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class UserNotAuthenticatedException   extends GenericException  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserNotAuthenticatedException  () {
        super(ExceptionKeys.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public UserNotAuthenticatedException  (Throwable cause) {
        super(ExceptionKeys.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION, cause);
    }

    public UserNotAuthenticatedException  (String messageKey) {
        super(messageKey);
    }

    public UserNotAuthenticatedException  (String messageKey, Throwable cause) {
        super(messageKey, cause);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    }
}
```

3) Create an error DTO :

```
@Data
public class ErrorDto {

    private int code;

    private String message;

    private String additionalData;

    public ErrorDto(String message, int code) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public ErrorDto(String message, String additionalData) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.additionalData = additionalData;
    }

    public ErrorDto() {
    }

}
```

4) Then create a global exception handler to map your exception with status :

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


    @ExceptionHandler({GenericException  .class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handlePortalExceptions(final GenericException   pex) {
        log.error("{} [{}]", pex.getClass().getName(), pex.getMessage());
        log.error(pex.getMessage(), pex);
        final ErrorDto errorDetails = new ErrorDto(pex.getMessage(), pex.getHttpStatus().value());
        errorDetails.setAdditionalData(pex.getCause() != null ? pex.getCause().getLocalizedMessage() : pex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, pex.getHttpStatus());
    }


    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(final Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        log.error("{} detected [{}]", ex.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        final ErrorDto errorDetails = new ErrorDto(ExceptionKeys.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        errorDetails.setAdditionalData(ex.getCause() != null ? ex.getCause().getLocalizedMessage() : ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but I would prefer to use annotations on exceptions.

Comment: I updated my response with annotation exception handler

Answer (score 0):

Below one solution that u can try

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SampleExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String otherExceptions(Exception e) {
if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
  throw e;

return "Internal Server Error";
```

}

}